# About compiler -l options (arm-linux-androideabi-gcc)

Tags: compiler-errors, android-ndk

When I use the make command (standalone_toolchain)

```
/opt/android-14-toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lpcap
```

The compiler seems to have no information about -lpcap

It seems to be related to the linker directive file.

If I use -lpcap option when I compile, I want to link libpcap.a

Do I need to add something to the ld file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, we use `-L` to provide the directory where the linker should look for libraries. So, for gcc, one will use

```
gcc -shared -o libmybest.so mybest.c -L ~/mydev/prebuild/arm -lpcap -llog
```

… and put the static library **libpcap.a** compiled for arm, to directory `~/mydev/prebuild/arm`.

When you build for Android with **bdk-build**, you would be tempted to write something like this in your **Android.mk** file:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)              #### don't use this block in real life!!!
LOCAL_MODULE    := mybest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += mybest.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -llog
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -L ~/mydev/prebuild/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI) -lpcap
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

***Don't do this!*** This worked on early releases of NDK, but is deprecated now.

Android NDK best practice is only to have system libraries (like **`libm`**, **`libdl`**, **`liblog`** listed in `LOCAL_LDLIBS`).

For third-party prebuilt libraries, you should use this:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := pcap
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ~/mydev/prebuild/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/liblpcap.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := ~/mydev/prebuild/include
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := mybest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += mybest.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -llog
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += pcap
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

This way, you have all information about **libpcap** in one block.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!